# how I can send sms to user when new record insert

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-haystack, django-smart-selects

I have model **Order**

```
class Order(models.Model):
STATUS = (
    ('Pending', 'Pending'),
    ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
    ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
)
shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, models.CASCADE, null=True)
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, models.CASCADE, null=True)
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, models.CASCADE, null=True)
quantity = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, )
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS, default='Pending')
note = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
```

how I can send SMS to shop when order insert by the customer then shop receive SMS that *You have new order by customer.name. the product.name in the quantity*

### customer model

```
class Customer(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default='customer')
     Phone = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=10)
```

### shop model

```
 class Shop(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, related_name='shop', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True, default='shop', )
      address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
      Phone = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=10)
```

and my order **views.py**

```
def CreateOrder(request, shop_id, product_id):
    customer = request.user.customer
    shop = Shop.objects.get(id=shop_id)
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    form = OrderForm()
    quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
    note = request.POST.get('note')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        order = Order.objects.create(customer=customer, shop=shop,
                                   product=product, quantity=quantity, note=note)
        return redirect('CustomerOrder')
```

Comment: Don't use `drf` tag, if you are not using it. I have seen many questions from you which follows the same pattern.

Comment: I've noticed, by the way, that all of your questions are left open. Have you seen [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? It helps signify that your problems have been solved. It's possible that you really didn't get a satisfactory answer to any; I just want to be sure you're aware of this feature

Answer (score 1):

You can use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/) in Django for that. Essentially your application will be notified when certain events occur. In your case you can use `post_save`, signal will be triggered after a model’s `save()` method is called. In Django docs you can check whole list of different types of `signals` available.

```
from .models import Order, Shop, Customer
from django.dispatch import Signal, receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


@receiver(post_save, sender=Order)
def send_msg_to_shop_owners(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # YOUR CODE HERE 
    pass
```

Inside `receiver`, you can use [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) to send API call to whatever message service you want to use.

**NOTE:** `post_save` signal will be `triggered` whenever `save()` method for your `Order` model is called. Which will include `updating` your model. So depending on your use case you can even create your own `custom signals`.

Custom signals in Django

```
from django.dispatch import Signal, receiver

# DEFINE SIGNAL NAME WITH REQUIRED ARGUMENTS; FOR NOW JUST order_id, user_name
send_message_to_shop_owner = Signal(providing_args=["order_id","user_name"])

@receiver(send_message_to_shop_owner)
def send_message_to_shop_owner_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
    # access the parameters passed
    # order_id = kwargs["order_id"]
    # user_name = kwargs["user_name"]
    # REST OF YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    pass
```

Now you have defined your `signal` you need to trigger it whenever you want to `send` message. In `drf` I generally place it inside `serializers.py` but you can do it inside your `views`.
Here is how you will trigger the signal.

`views.py`

```
from .signals import send_message_to_shop_owner

def CreateOrder(request, shop_id, product_id):
    customer = request.user.customer
    shop = Shop.objects.get(id=shop_id)
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    form = OrderForm()
    quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
    note = request.POST.get('note')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        order = Order.objects.create(customer=customer, shop=shop,
                                   product=product, quantity=quantity, note=note)
        # Ignore my custom parameters, instead of that you can send yours
        send_message_to_shop_owner.send(Sender=Order, order_id=order_id,user_name=user_name)
        return redirect('CustomerOrder')
```

**NOTE:** For `custom signals` you need to trigger it whenever you want to use it.